# Script can't find tool in backpack

Tags: lua, roblox

**1. Summarize the problem**

> My script can't find the tool in the player backpack. The output of the `print` is always nil.
> The toll is given by another script before the script that has to search it.
> No error message appears.

**2. Describe what you've tried**

> I've tried searching around but nothing fix my problem. I tried re-writing the code from 0 too.

**3. Show some code**

> **Simple script** Code that clone the tool and place it in the backpack

```lua
script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    
    local Frullato = game.ServerStorage.LemonadeStand.Tools.Frullato:Clone()
    Frullato.Parent = player.Backpack
    
    local Frappe = require(game.ServerScriptService.DummyMove)
    
end)
```

> **Simple script** Code that can't find the tool. Print output is "nil"

```lua
script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    
    local Smoothie = player.Backpack:GetChildren("Frullato")
    
    print(Smoothie.name)
end)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `:GetChildren()` use `:FindFirstChild()`, and "Smoothie.name" should be replaced with "Smoothie.Name"

Comment: It still doesn't work. The result of the print is nill again. (so it doesn't find the tool)